# graphing anomalies from population with R

Tags: r

I am working with a big time series data which looks like:

```
ProcesID ProcessName  StartDate  EndDate   Duration
   10       httpd      1/1/2012   1/2/1012  12 Hours
   11       ftp        1/1/2012   1/2/1012  10 Hours
   12       snmp       1/1/2012   1/2/1012  5 Hours
   13       email      1/1/2012   1/2/1012  2 Hours
   14       java       1/1/2012   1/2/1012  5 Hours
   15       perl       1/1/2012   1/2/1012  7 Hours
   20       php        1/1/2012   1/2/1012  6 Hours
```

Number of unique(`x$ProcessName`) is greater than 500. I cannot graph every `ProcessName`. I would like to pick the anamolies and graph them.

I did try sample:

```
 y<-x[sample(nrow(x), 50, prob = NULL),]

 ggplot(subset(x, ProcessName %in% y$ProcessName), 
       aes(StartDate, Duration, group=ProcessName)) + geom_point()
```

I am not sure if `sample` is the right choice to perform this analysis? Has anybody did something similar to create graphs from a populationg for only anomolies?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by anomoly? Are we talking about outliers? If so, is it a large number of hours that would make it an anomoly?

Comment: Anomaly would be if the duration of the process spikes. I would like to graph those processes data points.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, for example, process httpd's duration time is 12 hours on 1/1/20012. This process runs everday. Let's say, if this process'es duration is 20 hours on 1/30/2012, this is an anomaly and I would like to graph this process duration, etc.

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment than an answer, I'd start by looking at those days where a process is running longer than its 75th percentile for that process. These are just dummy data so it's unlikely to "work out" the way your data will, but you can use it as a framework for your own data. I expect that you'll see a few processes running heavy on specific days. You may want to subset your data into groups of 50 processes and then plot them. All 500+ would be too much to realistically review at one time.

If you're looking to compare one day to the previous day, I would look into using the `diff()` funciton.

Basically, the graph shows you which day(s) each process is running longer than it's 75th percentile.

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(ProcessID=factor(sample(1:50,10000,replace=TRUE)),
                  StartDate=as.Date(sample(1:5,10000,replace=TRUE), origin="2012-01-01"),
                  Duration=round(rexp(10000,rate=2)*6))

fourq.dat <- ddply(dat, .(ProcessID), summarize, fourq_hours = quantile(Duration)[4])
dat <- merge(dat,fourq.dat)
dat$plot <- ifelse(dat$Duration > dat$fourq_hours,1,0)

dat <- subset(dat, plot == 1)

ggplot(dat, aes(StartDate, Duration)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ProcessID)
```